# Excel request for splitting one column into two having two dates as text separated by carriage return

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I need help to split column A into Column A and B as below: Column A has dates as text and separated by carriage return.

[image]

I tried to use the formula

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2;CHAR(13);"");CHAR(10);"*")`

but getting the error as below( Coutrsey @arigo) :

[image]

Comment: What is the separator char in your system? Try to change semi-colon to comma.

Comment: @black cat : the separator is carriage return(new line) between two dates.

Comment: System List separator:  Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats -> Additional Settings -> Numbers -> List separator.  However did you try to replace it as i suggested?

Comment: @black cat : yes i replaced semi colon with comma in my formula but getting the same frustating error.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The formula works.

Comment: great, sorry after replacing with  comma it worked..............AWESOME THANKS BRO

Answer (score 0):

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(13),""),CHAR(10),"*")

This formula separate out the dates